# Cleaning Data Task in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-cleaning

Last week I failed at an exam because of one task. I would be very glad if someone could identify the mistake in my code and help me make sense of what I could improve.

**Specifically, I wonder if the to-be Nominal columns must be defined specifically by calling factor(). Same applies to the other columns - should I specify continuous to be "double", discrete to be "integer", ordinal to be "factor" etc. And if so, what would the date column be, as it is supposed to be discrete... would it be "date" or "int"?**

The task was as follows:

- Your output should be a dataframe named `clean_data`.
- All column names and values should match the table below.

| Column Name | Criteria |
| --- | --- |
| house_id | Nominal. Unique identifier for houses. Missing values not possible. |
| city | Nominal. The city in which the house is located. One of 'Silvertown', 'Riverford', 'Teasdale' and 'Poppleton' Replace missing values with "Unknown". |
| sale_price | Discrete. The sale price of the house in whole dollars. Values can be any positive number greater than or equal to zero.Remove missing entries. |
| sale_date | Discrete. The date of the last sale of the house. Replace missing values with 2023-01-01. |
| months_listed | Continuous. The number of months the house was listed on the market prior to its last sale, rounded to one decimal place. Replace missing values with mean number of months listed, to one decimal place. |
| bedrooms | Discrete. The number of bedrooms in the house. Any positive values greater than or equal to zero. Replace missing values with the mean number of bedrooms, rounded to the nearest integer. |
| house_type | Ordinal. One of "Terraced", "Semi-detached", or "Detached". Replace missing values with the most common house type. |
| area | Continuous. The area of the house in square meters, rounded to one decimal place. Replace missing values with the mean, to one decimal place. |

I am very much looking forward to your insights!
Note. This is a piece of code I have drafted after the exam, it might even be correct, since I haven't submitted it in this exact form.

Background info:

```
> str(house_sales)
'data.frame':   1500 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ house_id     : int  1217792 1900913 1174927 1773666 1258487 1539789 1353069 1155864 1608726 1358764 ...
 $ city         : chr  "Silvertown" "Silvertown" "Riverford" "Silvertown" ...
 $ sale_price   : int  55943 384677 281707 373251 328885 47143 429914 284440 87134 211203 ...
 $ sale_date    : chr  "2021-09-12" "2021-01-17" "2021-11-10" "2020-04-13" ...
 $ months_listed: num  5.4 6.3 6.9 6.1 8.7 5.1 NA 5.8 4.4 3 ...
 $ bedrooms     : int  2 5 6 6 5 2 6 4 2 4 ...
 $ house_type   : chr  "Semi-detached" "Detached" "Detached" "Det." ...
 $ area         : chr  "107.8 sq.m." "498.8 sq.m." "542.5 sq.m." "528.4 sq.m." ...



> str(clean_data)
'data.frame':   1500 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ house_id     : int  1217792 1900913 1174927 1773666 1258487 1539789 1353069 1155864 1608726 1358764 ...
 $ city         : chr  "Silvertown" "Silvertown" "Riverford" "Silvertown" ...
 $ sale_price   : num  55943 384677 281707 373251 328885 ...
 $ sale_date    : chr  "2021-09-12" "2021-01-17" "2021-11-10" "2020-04-13" ...
 $ months_listed: num  5.4 6.3 6.9 6.1 8.7 5.1 5.9 5.8 4.4 3 ...
 $ bedrooms     : num  2 5 6 6 5 2 6 4 2 4 ...
 $ house_type   : Factor w/ 3 levels "Terraced","Semi-detached",..: 2 3 3 3 3 2 3 3 2 3 ...
 $ area         : num  108 499 542 528 477 ...
```

My code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

house_sales <- read.csv("Downloads/house_sales.csv")

levels(as.factor(house_sales$house_type))

clean_data <- house_sales %>%
  # house_id    | Nominal. </br> Unique identifier for houses. </br>Missing values not possible.
  # Remove duplicate rows based on house_id
  distinct(house_id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  # city        | Nominal. </br>The city in which the house is located. One of 'Silvertown', 'Riverford', 'Teasdale' and 'Poppleton' </br>Replace missing values with "Unknown".
  # Replace missing values in city with "Unknown"
  mutate(city = ifelse(city == "--", "Unknown", city)) %>%
  # sale_price  | Discrete. </br>The sale price of the house in whole dollars. Values can be any positive number greater than or equal to zero.</br>Remove missing entries.
  # Replace missing values in sale_price with NA, remove rows with missing sale_price
  mutate(sale_price = ifelse(sale_price >= 0, round(sale_price,0), NA)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(sale_price)) %>%
  # sale_date   | Discrete. </br>The date of the last sale of the house. </br>Replace missing values with 2023-01-01.
  # Replace missing values in sale_date with "2023-01-01"
  mutate(sale_date = ifelse(is.na(sale_date), "2023-01-01", sale_date)) %>%
  # months_listed  | Continuous. </br>The number of months the house was listed on the market prior to its last sale, rounded to one decimal place. </br>Replace missing values with mean number of months listed, to one decimal place.
  # Replace missing values in months_listed with the mean (rounded to one decimal place)
  mutate(months_listed = round(ifelse(is.na(months_listed), mean(months_listed, na.rm = TRUE), months_listed),1)) %>%
  # bedrooms    | Discrete. </br>The number of bedrooms in the house. Any positive values greater than or equal to zero. </br>Replace missing values with the mean number of bedrooms, rounded to the nearest integer.
  # Replace missing values in bedrooms with the mean (rounded to the nearest integer)
  mutate(bedrooms = round(ifelse(is.na(bedrooms), mean(bedrooms, na.rm = TRUE), bedrooms))) %>%
  # house_type   | Ordinal. </br>One of "Terraced", "Semi-detached", or "Detached". </br>Replace missing values with the most common house type.
  # Convert variant names to standard names
  mutate(house_type = str_replace(house_type, "^Det\\.$", "Detached")) %>%
  mutate(house_type = str_replace(house_type, "^Semi$", "Semi-detached")) %>%
  mutate(house_type = str_replace(house_type, "^Terr\\.$", "Terraced")) %>%
  # Convert to factor
  mutate(house_type = factor(house_type, levels = c("Terraced", "Semi-detached", "Detached"))) %>%
  # area      | Continuous. </br>The area of the house in square meters, rounded to one decimal place. </br>Replace missing values with the mean, to one decimal place.
  # Replace missing values in area with the mean (rounded to one decimal place)
  mutate(area = round(as.numeric(gsub(" sq.m.", "", area)),1)) %>%
  mutate(area = ifelse(is.na(area), round(mean(area, na.rm = TRUE),1), area))
```

Comment: Your teacher will be in a much better position to evaluate how your work compares against their expectations. That said, a few suggestions: 1) Is it possible any missing `city` could be something besides "--", such as "-" or "" or NA? 2) always helpful to convert dates to Date format for further calculations, e.g. ` mutate(sale_date = ifelse(is.na(sale_date), "2023-01-01", as.Date(sale_date))) %>%` 3) I'm not sure the `house_type` adjustments are working as intended, e.g. I tried `"Detac"` as an input and it was not updated to "Detached." 4) is the `area` data consistently formatted?

Comment: Messy data can be messy in myriad ways, so you will be in a better position than us to review the cleaned data to see that the output is as clean as it can be. For instance, it's likely that you have made some assumptions about what kinds of formats you will receive, and some of those assumptions may be wrong. Review the NA's that you are imputing to the mean -- are all of the inputs truly NA, or might some just have slightly different formats? E.g a row could have `area` "1,000 sq.m." or "59 sq m" and those would error out even though that data might be fine.

Comment: what Jon said, plus, I'd say, a few other things: 1. when you have rows with duplicate house ids, are all of the other values in the row identical, or do you have values missing in one row but not another? 2. I think with the city names, it's probably better to have a city names vector, and do something like `city = ifelse(city %in% city_names, city, "Unknown") |> as.factor()`, 3. `sale_date = ifelse(is.na(sale_date), "2023-01-01", sale_date)` should be `sale_date = ifelse(is.na(sale_date), as.Date("2023-01-01"), as.Date(sale_date))`

Comment: 4. if the house type is ordinal data, you could use `ordered()`. 5. the regexes should probably be something like `str_replace(house_type, "^D.*", "Detached"))`

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious issue at a glance is that your one-line code is **unacceptablely long**.

I don't know your marking criteria for the exam, so I can only comment with respect general coding conventions.

You should know that `mutate()` can handle multiple columns, right? So, clearly you don't need 10 `mutate()`. Also, for 'sale_date ', you can convert it to date using `as.Date()`, and modify 'house_type' using `case_when()`.

Comment: I disagree that a dplyr chain like this is necessarily too long. I think it's more a question of style preference, how much complication/variety is involved (in this case, all steps are "clean a column" so they seem thematically related), and how you want to handle error checking as you go. Since most columns are only getting touched once, I don't see much downside to this style.

Comment: datetime seems a bad choice for a sale date since it doesn't have a set time. Date makes more sense. (But I'd note the rubric inexplicably wants a discrete variable here, ie character or factor, when a continuous Date seems the clear choice to me.)

Comment: @Jon Spring Yeah, use as.Date then. I oversaw the data. Generally, for data types, I've said it is dependent on the marking criteria to say which one is preferable and deserves higher scores. I do think it is unnecessarily long and duplicated, and I would say confidently that is not something in college teachers' intended learning outcomes, because I had experience assisting that kind of marking with assigned marking criteria. However, it is your freedom and personal habit to do it the other way.